# String Key Concatenation Sourced from Fields

Tags: string

I have thousands of duplicate Opportunity Contact Roles, I am trying to create a key so I may determine which ones are duplicates.

I can not for the life of me figure out how to make a string out of a series field values.

```
List<OpportunityContactRole> ocr = [SELECT Id, ContactId, IsDeleted, IsPrimary, OpportunityId, Role FROM OpportunityContactRole];

List<String> keys = new List<String>();

for(OpportunityContactRole o : ocr) {

// How to I build my key? 
String key = o.ContactId + o.IsDeleted + o.IsPrimary + o.OpportunityId + o.Role;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use String.valueOf to arbitrarily convert almost any value to a string:

```
String key = o.ContactId + String.valueOf(o.IsDeleted) + String.valueOf(o.IsPrimary) + o.OpportunityId + o.Role;
```

I'd recommend that you not use IsDeleted or really even IsPrimary, leaving just ContactId, OpportunityId, and Role. This would let you use the OpportunityTeamMember object as a key directly:

```
Set<OpportunityContactRole> roles = new Set<OpportunityContactRole>();
Id[] duplicates = new Id[0];
for(OpportunityContactRole role: [SELECT ContactId, OpportunityId, Role FROM OpportunityContactRole]) {
    OpportunityContactRole key = new OpportunityContactRole(ContactId=role.ContactId, OpportunityId=role.OpportunityId, Role=role.Role);
    if(roles.contains(key)) {
        duplicates.add(role.Id);
    } else {
        roles.add(key);
    }
}
delete duplicates;
```